# Raspian not booting after editing fstab and reverting changes

Tags: boot-issues, mount, headless, fstab

I have a RaspberryPi3 with a headless stretch installation. It ran a VPN server and a DNS server. Today I wanted to mount a HDD to use as a place to drop files in the LAN following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/etes/aa76a6e9c80579872e5f). After editing the fstab the system wouldn't boot. I then got the SD card and opened the drive under windows with ext2fsd, located the fstab file, found my changes and reverted them. The pi still won't boot. How can I fix this? I'd rather not wipe the SD and reinstall everything.

EDIT: I just found out that my SD card mounted under windows with ext2fsd is mounted in read-only mode. I can hit save in notepad++ but the file doesn't change. How can I write to that SD card?

EDIT2: Fixed it now. Was able to find a bootable linux DVD from which I was able to change the files of the SD card as root. Linux is so nice and tells you when the fail saves, which windows(Notepad++) did not. The last question still remains: How to mount an ext4 linux drive under windows to be able to change faulty config files?

EDIT3: Got it working by adding the following line to fstab:

```
UUID=<MYUID> /mounts/MOUNTFORTHISDISK ntfs-3g rw,default 0 0
```

fstab concents:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=eda353fb-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=eda353fb-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
/dev/sda1 /mnt/mybook /ntfs defaults 0 0 # this is the faulty line
```

Comment: Just restore from your backup

Comment: That'd be not quite recent enough. Is there no way to fix this in the filesystem? After all I just changed a line in fstab.. can't this be reverted?

Comment: please add the content of `/etc/fstab` and search `/var/log/syslog` for "systemd-fsck"

Comment: I just remounted the sd and saw that the faulty line is still there despite me removing and saving it; this makes me thing ext2fsd is mounting it in readonly mode. How can I mount this in read-write mode under windows?

Comment: @Fabian I was unable to locate a syslog folder in /var/log/ but I found out that fstab did not change after me editing it. How to mount in rw mode under windows?

Comment: Remove the "faulty" `/dev/sda1` line in fstab ... boot the Pi... Plug in the external HDD ... enter the following command in the Pi's terminal `blkid` ... use the `UUID` in your fstab instead of `/dev/sda1` ... `UUID=72bfc10d-73ec....`  Be aware that [NTFS has some extra requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab#113746)

Comment: @RubberStamp: the OP wants to know how he can change /etc/fstab, since ext2fsd gives only read access.

Comment: fixed it now with a linux boot CD. @RubberStamp so to auto mount I just need to replace my faulty line with `UUID=<MYUID> /mnt/mybook /ntfs defaults 0 0` ?

How to I correctly auto-mount my HDD as rw?

Comment: If the drive is NTFS, you'll need to install the `ntfs-3g` package on the RPi3 before you can mount the drive as read/write... and then follow the link I posted above... or [search the Unix/Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=ntfs+fstab)  ... NTFS is not the most friendly FS to work with outside of the MS Windows world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mount I used did not edit the file even though saving worked without any warnings. Mounting via ext2fsd seems to be readonly. Grabbed a Linux DVD, booted my pc into there and fixed it with gedit in root. Correct line to mount is in initial question. Thanks for everyone that stepped me through in the comments!